# How to perform addition and subtraction of values from individual cells of a database table in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

[image: Example of a database table.]

This picture is visual example of database table made in excel.

How do you make cell G6 the sum of G5 and C6 and then subtract D6 and E6 from it? And that every lower cell of the G7, G8... should have the same scheme. I used Django Aggregation to sum the values from each column, but I can't handle adding and subtracting individual cells.

Comment: what is the relation between G6 and G5? All the other values( D6,C6,...) are from one row and it's ok. But about the cell G5 you mentioned, please indicate the general relation between them.

Comment: @ali jafarzadeh G5 and G6 are cells of the same column but different records. The relationship between them is such that G5 is a component of the action whose result is to be G6. G6=G5+C6-D6-E6

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to di it like below.

First you can use pandas library to manipulate excel tables.

```
import pandas as pd
```

than you can read your excel file:

```
file_path = 'path_to_your_excel_file.xlsx' # Update with your file path
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
```

than you can iterate over len(df) => number of rows you have and make recording calculations:

```
# Assuming 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G' are the column headers as shown in the picture.
for i in range(5, len(df)): # Starting from row index 5 (6th row in Excel)
    df.loc[i, 'G'] = df.loc[i-1, 'G'] + df.loc[i, 'C'] - df.loc[i, 'D'] - df.loc[i, 'E']
```

and save your changes as excel file:

```
output_file_path = 'path_to_output_excel_file.xlsx' # Update with your desired output file path
df.to_excel(output_file_path, index=False)
```

Comment: Looks great @Berkay Gökmen, but I need to work on the database in Django, Excel was only used to create a visual example of the database table structure.

Comment: @Krzysztof - above approach should also work instead of setting the ```df = pd.read_sql_query("select No, Year, A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H from table, con=<add connection details>)```